# How can I make my Pidgey have 300+ CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

How can I get a Pidgey that has 300+ CP, right now, the Pidgey's I get can only have like a maximum of about 100ish CP. All help appreciated.

Comment: level up, and you will get higher cp pokemon in the wild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways:

- Power up your pidgey using candies and stardust
- If you want to find higher cp pokemon in the wild then level up your trainer level and you will naturally find higher cp pokemon

Comment: I powered up my Pidgey to max CP Percentage and it is still like 100 Cp

Comment: @RainMaker Your Pokemon's max CP is determined in most part by your trainer level. The more you level up the higher you can get them and the higher they can be in the wild.